# How do I setup a naked domain on Google sites using Google domains?

Tags: no-www, google-sites, google-domains

I've got a Google Domain and I'm trying to link it with my Google Sites page. If you go to `www.example.com`, the site loads, But going to `example.com` doesn't work. It seems to need the WWW to load the page with the correct link in the URL bar.

How can I change this? I just want `example.com` to go to my site whilst keeping the URL `example.com` in the URL bar.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think that Google Sites requires the `www`.   They allow you to redirect to add the `www`, but don't allow you to browse your Google site without the `www`.

Comment: Google Domain and google sites page means site.google.com?
If you have your domain, you should redirect www.example.com to example.com
This is like http to https redirecting.
you can get supporting from your domain hosting company support.
Good luck!